# SQLite throws 'database locked' exception way before timeout has passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have quite a large python3 application (20.000 lines) that uses the SQLite database intensively. It has a web-ui and API, which leads to it having 10 threads for the web server and 2-3 other threads. All these threads can write to the database, so there could be a fair bit of concurrency. There is one database connection per thread.

The problem my application has been having since the start is that the database will lock sometimes (the 'Database is locked' error). As far as I know, this happens when two connections want to write to the database, but one has not committed their changes before the timeout of the other connection (waiting to write) has passed.

The peculiar thing that I have noticed is that sometimes I get the error within seconds of the application starting up. I have my timeout set to 20 seconds (`sqlite3.connect('database.db', timeout=20.0)`), but I will get the error after like 2 seconds of the application starting up. How can this happen? [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) states that the timeout parameter decides how long the connection should wait on a lock before it gives up. So how can it give up after 2 seconds when I set my value to 20 seconds?

Comment: "a fair bit of concurrency" isn't really what sqlite was designed for.

Comment: `uses the SQLite database intensively. It has a web-ui and API` that's a very bad design. SQLite is a *single* user embedded database. It has *no* locking or concurrency mechanisms. Even when you use WAL mode, writers won't block other readers or writers. A background job will apply changes written to the log on every checkpoint. Until that point, everyone will read "old" data.

Comment: Both comments aren't relevant to the question. The problem is that an exception is thrown after 2 seconds even though the timeout is 20 seconds. The application is not time sensitive at all, and is used by a single user at most, at all times. So there are most likely not more than 2 connections writing at the same time. When two writes are happening at the same time, they will probably be unrelated to each other (because a user can only do one thing at a time), so old data for a short time also isn't a problem.

Comment: To add: with 'concurrency', I meant that 2 connections can both start writing a lot of data at the same time. So _few connections making big writes_, not _loads of connections making small writes_. That's why I set the timeout from 5 to 20, because the connections just need to wait on each other (which could take time because of the big writes) and write when they can. It doesn't matter that it happens multiple seconds later and maybe in a different order, because the application is not time sensitive and isn't affected much by old data.

Comment: What happens if you (1) Use [`PRAGMA busy_timeout`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout), or (2) pass `isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE'` to your `sqlite3.connect` statement?

Comment: @dan04 I checked the busy_timeout and when I set it to `20.0` in the connect statement, then check `PRAGMA busy_timeout;`, it is indeed set to `20000`ms, so that is working and changing that won't help. So I'm going to try the change in `isolation_level` and see if that makes any difference :)

Comment: It seems like setting the isolation_level to 'EXCLUSIVE' helped. I haven't had any database locks since. It doesn't necessarily mean that it has completely resolved the problem (the error would raise pretty randomly and with various rate) so it could also be that I have just been lucky and didn't encounter it, regardless of the isolation level. Either way, it seems like the solution for now so please submit it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't figure out why your attempts to set a 20-second busy timeout (either with the `timeout` parameter or the SQL [`PRAGMA busy_timeout`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) statement) aren't working.  But our discussion in the comments found a workaround:

[`sqlite3.connect`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) has an optional `isolation_level` parameter, which controls the database locking behavior during transactions.

- In `DEFERRED` (the default) mode, a transaction acquires a read lock on the database when it begins, and a write lock only when a write operation is requested.
- In `IMMEDIATE` mode, a transaction acquires a write lock immediately, even if it's only performing read operations.  Other transactions attempting to write to the database will be blocked, but read-only transactions can still proceed.
- In `EXCLUSIVE` mode, a transaction acquires an exclusive lock on the database, blocking all other transactions, reading *or* writing, until the current transaction is committed or rolled back.

Using `EXCLUSIVE` mode seems to have solved your immediate problem.